# Blazor + Azure AD authentication: Single Tenant login giving "Sorry, there's nothing at this address"

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, blazor

I'm setting up a single-tenant authentication on Azure AD, but after I click on the login button, I'm sent to an empty page saying "Sorry, there's nothing at this address".

If I try a multi-tenant application, I can login correctly, but I want this to be available only to users in the company

I'm using a test tenant, and here goes the code related:

appsettings.json:

```json
  "Microsoft": {
    "AppId": "30582132-28cc-#################", 
    "AppSecret": "Pbl8Q~mSnfXx.####################",
    "TenantId": "5d01008c-86dc-####################" 
  }
```

Program.cs:

```csharp
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
    .AddCookie(opt =>
    {
        opt.Cookie.Name = "AuthCookie";
    })
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(opt =>
    {
        opt.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        opt.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Microsoft:AppId"];
        opt.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Microsoft:AppSecret"];
        opt.AuthorizationEndpoint = builder.Configuration["Microsoft:TenantId"];
    });
```

MainLayout.razor:

```csharp
@layout TelerikLayout
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@using System.Security.Claims

<PageTitle>Marker.Web</PageTitle>

<div class="page">
    <main>
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                @context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="login/logout">Logout</a>
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="login/microsoft?RedirectUri=/">Login</a>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeView>
        <article>
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

LoginController:

```csharp
    [Route("/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("microsoft")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(string RedirectUri)
        {
            var props = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = RedirectUri
            };
            return Challenge(props, MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        [HttpGet("logout")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
            return Redirect("/");
        }
    }
```

The error message comes from App.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
                DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

[On Azure this is the RedirectUri](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ONE.png)

[Single-tenant setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zhVu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Change the path in the portal to:

```
https://localhost:7011/authentication/login-callback
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line

```
opt.AuthorizationEndpoint = builder.Configuration["Microsoft:TenantId"];
```

That needs to be a url for single tenant.

```
 microsoftOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
 microsoftOptions.TokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token";
```